# Check whether certain amount of time elapsed

Tags: c, time

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to see if X seconds have elapsed. The basic implementation I have in mind is as follows:

```
wait_for = 5;   // 5 seconds

ready_at = current_time() + wait_for;    // might wrap around! :(


...

/* There is no sleep call; there will be processing happening. */

...


if (current_time() >= ready_at)     // might also have wrapped around!
    do_stuff()
```

Pretty simple, right? The catch is that the process itself will be very long running, and although the `wait_for` time will be very brief in comparison, I worry that `current_time` will wrap around and the event won't fire. For obvious reasons, this code is rather annoying to test.

So my questions are:

1. What is the best time resolution method to use? I prefer something that is in posix, but linux-compatible is good enough. Tenth-of-a-second resolution is good enough. (That said, the check might not be executed for over an hour in particularly bad cases!)
2. How to properly deal with time wrapping around for both
   a) the calculation of ready_at, and
   b) the check whether or not it is ready?

Firing `do_stuff()` early is not really an option.

I'm well aware the logic of this should not be too difficult on its own, but I'm reasoning myself in circles on this one. My mind simply won't cooperate with me.

Comment: You’re worried about… integer overflow? Maybe you should find out whether that’s relevant. (It’s not for a 64-bit integer.) Anyway, use `clock_gettime` (posix) and pass `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: I'm worried about overflow as well as the timer wrapping around, thus ruining the check.

Comment: Surely, if you worried that clock_t is going to loop. Why do you need a time at that precision. Use minutes and seconds

Comment: @Stigma: Oh, you mean 23:59 → 0:00 and such? `clock_gettime` doesn’t return the time of day; don’t worry.

Comment: The only way I can think to get a finer accuracy without clock_t, is create a ticker thread sleeping for a micro second or something. This will obvious effect your result as processing time in this thread. Don't try using a ticking process as from experience I found the latency getting the time w as an inacceptabe.